# How can I resize my Lion partition to fill up the unused space on the drive?

Tags: macos, disk-utility, partition, recovery

My MacBook (Late 2007) has an 80GB hard drive. I used to have a 15GB Boot Camp partition, and deleted it at some point -- but I forgot to resize my Snow Leopard partition to fill the 15GB of free space at the end of the drive.

Since then I installed Lion. When I [start from the recovery partition](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/18180/unable-to-resize-lion-partition) and try to resize it, Disk Utility fails with the error: `Couldn't unmount disk`.

I'm guessing this is happening because the 500mb recovery partition (which I booted from) is in the way. Here's what I get when I run `diskutil list`:

```
/dev/disk0
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *80.0 GB    disk0
   1:                        EFI                         209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD            65.3 GB    disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
```

How can I move the Recovery HD partition to the end of the drive so I can resize my main system partition and get that 15GB of space back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**My suggestion**

Don't try to resize from the Recovery partition. Boot into the normal partition and resize from there.

**Background**

diskutil list is misleading you. It is not the position of the recovery partition which is your problem.

I had a very similar setup, and here is the output of diskutil list for me:

```
  #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.1 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI                         209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD            423.6 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
   4:                  Apple_HFS Temp Partition Test ... 74.8 GB    disk0s4
   5:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             792.2 MB   disk0s5
```

Partitions 4 and 5 had a dev version of Lion on them. I have just used Disk utility to delete partitions 4 and 5 and resize partition 2 to fill the space.

This worked - Disk Utility resized the main drive with no problem. So what have I done which is different to you? Well, I resized the main partition from booting into the main partition **not the Recovery Partiion**. You **can** resize a partition that you have booted from in Disk Utility.

It makes sense that the recovery partition would "get in the way" if you have booted from it, so I suspect that above suggestion might work for you.

Comment: Resizing it from Lion worked fine. Disk Utility took care of everything. (I swear I remember trying to do it this way earlier today, but DU wasn't showing the unpartitioned space on the drive. In retrospect, this may have been because I had FileVault enabled at the time.)

Comment: Great! I'm glad I could be of help. Thanks for pushing my reputation into 4 figures too! :-)

Comment: I've been looking for this answer for too long! Thanks! +1